# How to quickly disable / enable stages in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

When you work on your `.gitlab-ci.yml` for a big project, for example having a time consuming testing stage causes a lot of delay. Is there an easy way to disable that stage, as just removing it from the `stages` definition, will make the YAML invalid from Gitlab's point of view (since there's a defined but unused stage), and in my case results in:

```
test job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, build, deploy, .post
```

Since YAML does not support block comments, you'd need to comment out every line of the offending stage.

Are there quicker ways?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could disable all the jobs from your stage using this trick of starting the job name with a dot ('`.`'). See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#hide-jobs for more details.

```yaml
.hidden_job:
  script:
    - run test
```

Answer (score 64):

There is a way to disable individual jobs (but not stages) like this:

```
test:
  stage: test
  when: manual
```

The jobs are skipped by default, but still can be triggered in the UI:

[image: Gitlab CI screenshot]

Comment: How can we disable top play button on stage based on certain condition ??

Comment: @mayur_mitkari, not sure if that's possible, sorry.

Comment: @mayur_mitkari you can set a rule based on some kinds of conditions, for example variable values (only at the time the pipeline is created, I believe). Formatting will be wrong here, but something like `rules:
    - if: $ENABLE_JOB == '1'
      when: manual`

Answer (score 54):

Also possible with `rules` and `when` as below:

```
test:
  stage: test
  rules:
   - when: never
```

Comment: the issue here is that if the job is needed by another one, then the pipeline will fail.

Answer (score 5):

So far, the easiest way I've found is to use a `rules` definition like so:

```
test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '"1" != "1"'
(...)
```

This still feels a bit odd, so if you have a better solution, I'll gladly accept another answer.

Comment: I don't know what language this is or how the syntax should be, but I'm pretty sure you can just use `false` or `0` instead of `"1" != "1"`. But `when: never` is more simple & descriptive anyway.

Comment: @Daniel Well, you can't use `false` or `0` - This is why I came up with this contraption in the first place! So this answer still serves it's purpose as an alternative solution, while the correct one is the leading dot, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Best way to "comment-out" whole stage in a single line is to have the stage description inside an individual file and commenting-out the include line.

See Gitlab docs on [Include directive](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include). This file splitting approach is generally very useful for big gitlab-ci files.

For example:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml

include:
  - local: ".gitlab-ci.build.yml"
# Temporarily disabled
#  - local: ".gitlab-ci.test.yml"
  - local: ".gitlab-ci.release.yml"
```