# Is there a better way to disable/skip a job in a GitLab CI pipeline than commenting everything out?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a job in a GitLab CI pipeline that I want to temporarily disable because it is not working. My test suites are running locally but not inside docker, so until I figure that out I want to skip the test job or the test stage.

I tried commenting out the stage, but then I get an error message from the CI validation: `test job: chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, build, deploy, .post`

So I can simply comment out the entire job, but I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out, there is! It's quite at the end of the very thorough documentation of GitLab CI:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#hide-jobs

Instead of using comments on the job or stage, simply prefix the job name with a dot `.`.

Example from the official documentation:

```yaml
.hidden_job:
  script:
    - run test
```

Comment: This does not work that well when you use templates that are located in a dedicated repo and `include`d.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992049/how-to-quickly-disable-enable-stages-in-gitlab-ci/64992332#64992332