# How to quickly disable / enable entire stages in Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab-ci pipeline consisting of multiple stages:

```yaml
stages:
  - lint
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

sast:
  stage: lint
include:
- template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

clang-format:
  stage: lint
# ...
```

All stages consist of multiple jobs.

Now, I would like to temporarily and quickly disable an entire stage (`lint`), that is: all jobs that are assigned to that stage should be skipped.

I know that I can disable single jobs by [hiding](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#hide-jobs) them.
I've also read [How to quickly disable / enable stages in Gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992049/) (for which the accepted answer is to just hide the jobs you don't want to run).

But hiding jobs selectively does not scale well (consider: templated pipelines; included pipelines; multiple jobs/stage).

So my question is: Can I disable an *entire stage* without having to adjust each job?

Comment: move the stage at the end of the list and add a failing job before the last stage, with that your pipeline will stop before launching those jobs

Comment: thanks. but that makes my pipeline fail...

Comment: to be tested instead of a failing job a manual job, this will block the continuation and I am pretty sure the pipeline will be green

Comment: tested pipeline is blocked

Comment: thanks. the *other* drawback is, that it requires to move the stage around. my solution for now is to have a base `.lint` job that all other lint-jobs extend, and which can be set to `when: never`. This doesn't really propagate to the templated SAST-jobs, but there i can set the `SAST_DISABLED` variable. this strikes me as less invasive then the manual-job solution.